# Allow access to gallery photos programatically

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, popupwindow, photo-gallery

In my app I take the snap shot of the screen and save it to the iPad's gallery as below

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

But then it shows a pop up saying

**"App" Would Like to Access Your Photos**
with
**Don't Allow** and **OK** button

After I tap **OK** it save he image to the gallery but I want to handle this popup programmatically.
I don't want to show popup to user.

I am using ios7

Is this possible and how it can be done ?

Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with ios6 this is automatically appear Alert This is Native API from Apple that show Message for User Allow it we can't handle it programmatic. if you can by some trick might be you are not able to access the Photo Gallary and also Might be Apple reject your app Too.